# Extracting part of a image name in php

Tags: php, image

I am working in a php language .I am getting the data from fronthand . My problem is that  I am getting a image source name **./gearedup-pics/pc_52399950497a3.png** like this using post method but i need the just the name of the image ie **pc_52399950497a3.png** . I m storing in $cpic . so how can i get only the image name ?

Comment: use this $info = new SplFileInfo('/path/to/foo.txt');
var_dump($info->getFilename());

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get file name from full path with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$baseName = basename($cpic);
```

See http://php.net/manual/function.basename.php

Answer (score 1):

hey plz check out this

```
    $name = 'gearedup-pics/pc_52399950497a3.png';
   $parts = pathinfo($name);
   var_dump($parts);
```

which will get you like a array

```
     'dirname' => string 'gallery/painting' (length=16)
    'basename' => string 'some_image_name.jpg' (length=19)
    'extension' => string 'jpg' (length=3)
  'filename' => string 'some_image_name' (length=15)
```

like

```
    echo $parth['basename'];
```

and other wise you this link

**1)  [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)**
**2)  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236083/get-file-name-from-path-with-php-and-regular-expressions)**
**3) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278120/extract-filename-from-path)**
**4)[link4](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)**

Answer (score 0):

[`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)should give you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
$cpic = substr(strrchr($pic_name, '/'), 1);
```

Even though Phil's answer might be easier!